# Javascript - Accessing data from array after converting from csv file

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I am importing a csv file into my project which I converted into an array. I am able to get the my data back as an array but I am having a hard time accessing the data inside of it due to how it is structured.

For example, when console.logging my array `cardDataList` I get a return of:

```
[…]
​
0: "State"
​
1: "202"
​
3: "129,491"
​
```

Now with this data I am attempting to append to an HTML id but I am having an issue properly targeting one of the objects. For example, if I'd like to append to an id using `0: "State"` I am unable to do `cardData[0].0`. I've also tried `cardData[0].["name"]` but that is returning undefined. My expected outcome is to target each object as it if it were a json object.

For example, if the array was

```
[...]
Name: "State"
```

I can access the data by doing `cardData[0].Name`

Here is my code:

```
function getCardData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: cardData,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {


        let cardDataList = [];
        let csvObjects = $.csv.toObjects(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < csvObjects.length; i++) {
            name = csvObjects[i]["StateName"];
            population = csvObjects[i]["Population"];
            business = csvObjects[i]["Businesses"];

            var arrCardListItem = [
                name,
                population,
                business,];

            cardDataList.push(arrCardListItem);

        }


        const urlStr= window.location.pathname;

        if (urlStr.includes('/state/')) {
            console.log(cardDataList[0])
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access it like an object, then make your cardDataList an array of objects. 
Consider:

```
var arr = []
var name = 'test'
var population = 'testpop'

var obj = {
    name, 
    population
}
arr.push(obj)
console.log(arr[0])
console.log(arr[0].name)
```

result

```
Object
name: "test"
population: "testpop"
__proto__: Object
```

```
test
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused on what you mean by this. It seems that you are assigning the variable and pushing it. In relation to my `cardDataList` array that has values in there already, how would I execute the example you have shown?

Comment: so right now you're creating these variables from your CSV converted array:
          `name = csvObjects[i]["StateName"];
            population = csvObjects[i]["Population"];
            business = csvObjects[i]["Businesses"];` and then assigning them as a nested array. Try to make `var arrCardListItem = [
                name,
                population,
                business,];` an object instead. just change the square brackets for arrCardListItem to `{}`

Comment: i.e. `var arrCardListItem = {
                name,
                population,
                business};` now after you push each arrCardListItem to your array, you can access the value you like `cardDataList[0].name, cardDataList[0].population` etc

Comment: if you don't want to do that, and keep the current data structure, just access the value by cardDataList[0][0], cardDataList[0][1] etc

Comment: Both examples you just mentioned seemed to be getting my the results I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: no problem, let me know if you want more explanation as to why